# Print output of ls -l | awk something

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I want to get the output of command in a python script. The command is pretty straightforward - `ls -l $filename | awk '{print $5}'`, essentially capture the size of a file

I have tried a couple of ways but I somehow can't get the variable filename passed in correctly.

What am I doing wrong with either approach?

Thanks for the help

Have tried two different ways as below:

### Method 1

```
name = subprocess.check_output("ls -l filename | awk '{print $5}'", shell=True)
print name
```

Here `ls` complains that filename does not exist which I totally understand, but I am not sure what I would do to pass filename as a variable

### Method 2

```
first = ['ls', '-l', filename]
second = ['awk', ' /^default/ {print $5}']
p1 = subprocess.Popen(first, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(second, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = p2.stdout.read()
print out
```

Here it just prints nothing.

actual result would be the size of the file.

Comment: Have you looked at the builtin Python module OS to do this?

Comment: Using `ls` for this is bad practice even in bash, much less in Python; see [BashFAQ #87](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087) and [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: That said, what's with the `^default` in your `awk`? You're printing the size only of a file with a name that starts with `default`, and ignoring any other filename. Why not just `second = ['awk', '{print $5}']` for parity with your "first" comand? (To be clear, **under no circumstances** should you actually use this approach in production code, but fixing it may be helpful to demonstrate that the problems are with the awk code, not with how you're using it from Python).

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex, I did, have been using OS. But then came across an article that OS should no longer be used and supposedly subprocess is better.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, newbie to python here, did not realize default had to be something. Will look it up.

Comment: @droidian, it's specifically `os.system()`, `os.popen()` and the like that should be replaced with `subprocess`. See [Replacing older functions with the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module) on docs.python.org; anything that it's not telling you to replace with `subprocess` you can still use.

Comment: @droidian did any of the methods in my answer work for you?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex, Yes, all the examples worked. I just had to debate between using OS versus subprocess and I preferred to use the OS method. Also the stat -f shown below is a bsd specific command. stat -c %s filename works on linux/GNU. Thanks for all the help

Comment: I'm using Mac OS, hence the -f. Since all the answers worked please accept my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The builtin Python module `os` can provide you the size of a specific file.

Here is the documentation related to the methods below.

[os.stat - reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat)

[os.path.getsize - reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize)

Here are two methods using the Python module `os` to obtain the filesize:

```
import os

# Use os.stat with st_size
filesize_01 = os.stat('filename.txt').st_size
print (filesize_01)
# outputs 
30443963

# os.path.getsize(path) Return the size, in bytes, of path.
filesize_02 = os.path.getsize('filename.txt')
print (filesize_02)
# outputs 
30443963
```

I'm adding this `subprocess` example, because of the conversations concerning the use of `os` on this question. I decided to use the `stat` command over the `ls` command. I'm also using `subprocess.check_output` instead of `subprocess.Popen`, which was used in your question. The example below can be added to a try block with error handling.

[subprocess.check_output - reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

```
from subprocess import check_output

def get_file_size(filename):

   # stat command
   # -f display information using the specified format
   # the %z format selects the size in bytes
   output = check_output(['stat', '-f', '%z', str({}).format(filename)])

   # I also use the f-string in this print statement.
   # ref: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/
   print(f"Filesize of {filename} is: {output.decode('ASCII')}")
   # outputs 
   30443963

get_file_size('filename.txt')
```

My personal preference is the `os` module, but yours might be the `subprocess` module.

Hopefully, one of these three methods will help solve your question.

Comment: The third last line should have "02", not "01", but the editor won't accept the correction unless I make gratuitous changes to 5 other characters too.

Comment: @RayButterworth THANKS.  Cut and paste kills the best of us.

Comment: Initially I was reading the "use `os` instead" advice to be suggesting `os.popen()` or similar, but what you were *actually* suggesting is indeed the far better practice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Thanks. These methods seemed cleaner and securer over the subprocess ones.

Comment: So you guys saying it is ok to use OS over subprocess?

Comment: @droidian, it's **not** okay to use `os.system()` or `os.popen()` or any other part of `os` that does the same things `subprocess` does. But the parts of `os` you're being told to use here do *completely different* things from `subprocess`.